# Error in creating ocf:heatbeat:apache reource using peacemaker in centOS 7 server

Tags: apache, server, centos, cluster-computing

I'm now trying to create HA cluster using peacemaker on centOS.I am now currently reading and following the steps and instructions of this documentation book "http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-pcs/pdf/Clusters_from_Scratch/Pacemaker-1.1-Clusters_from_Scratch-en-US.pdf".In section 6.4(page 34-35), the ocf:heartbeat:apache resource that I'hv added to my cluster is stopped.Can anyone tell me whats wrong with my cluster nodes please?I have also created “/etc/httpd/conf.d/status.conf” file to enable apache status url for peacemaker. 
I have two nodes "cluster1 and cluster2".This is the terminal informatin when i type "pcs status" command

```
Cluster name: mycluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: cluster3 (version 1.1.15-11.el7_3.2-e174ec8) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Sun Jan  1 11:10:37 2017      Last change: Sun Jan  1 10:47:03 2017 by root via cibadmin on cluster1

2 nodes and 3 resources configured

Online: [ cluster1 cluster3 ]

Full list of resources:

 CLusterIP  (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):   Started cluster3
 WebSite    (ocf::heartbeat:apache):    Stopped
 WebSite2   (ocf::heartbeat:apache):    Stopped

Failed Actions:
* WebSite_start_0 on cluster3 'unknown error' (1): call=70, status=Timed Out, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Sat Dec 31 18:49:19 2016', queued=0ms, exec=40003ms
* WebSite2_start_0 on cluster3 'unknown error' (1): call=83, status=Timed Out, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Sat Dec 31 19:20:05 2016', queued=0ms, exec=40004ms
* WebSite_start_0 on cluster1 'unknown error' (1): call=66, status=Timed Out, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Sun Jan  1 10:16:30 2017', queued=1ms, exec=40001ms
* WebSite2_start_0 on cluster1 'unknown error' (1): call=78, status=Timed Out, exitreason='none',
    last-rc-change='Sun Jan  1 10:47:16 2017', queued=0ms, exec=40003ms


Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/disabled
  pacemaker: active/disabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Here are the logs when I type "journalctl -xe"

> Jan 01 10:47:38 cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23618]: INFO: waiting for
>   apache /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:39 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23625]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:39
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23632]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:40 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23639]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:40
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23646]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:41 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23653]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:41
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23660]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:42 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23667]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:42
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23674]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:43 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23682]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:44
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23689]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:45 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23696]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:45
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23703]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:46 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23710]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:46
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23717]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:47 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23724]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:47
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23731]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:48 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23738]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:48
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23745]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:49 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23752]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:49
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23759]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:50 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23766]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:50
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23773]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:51 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23784]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:51
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23791]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:52 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23798]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:52
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23805]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:53 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23812]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:53
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23819]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:54 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23840]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:54
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23847]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:55 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23854]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:55
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23861]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:56 cluster1
>   apache(WebSite2)[23868]: INFO: apache not running Jan 01 10:47:56
>   cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23875]: INFO: waiting for apache
>   /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to come up Jan 01 10:47:56 cluster1
>   lrmd[14090]:  warning: WebSite2_start_0 process (PID 23247) timed out
>   Jan 01 10:47:56 cluster1 lrmd[14090]:  warning: WebSite2_start_0:23247
>   - timed out after 40000ms Jan 01 10:47:56 cluster1 crmd[14093]:    error: Result of start operation for WebSite2 on cluster1: Timed Out
>   Jan 01 10:47:56 cluster1 apache(WebSite2)[23922]: INFO: apache is not
>   running. Jan 01 10:47:56 cluster1 crmd[14093]:   notice: Result of
>   stop operation for WebSite2 on cluster1: 0 (ok) Jan 01 11:01:01
>   cluster1 systemd[1]: Started Session 7 of user root.
>   -- Subject: Unit session-7.scope has finished start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> ### -- Unit session-7.scope has finished starting up.
>
> -- The start-up result is done. Jan 01 11:01:01 cluster1 systemd[1]: Starting Session 7 of user root.
>   -- Subject: Unit session-7.scope has begun start-up
>   -- Defined-By: systemd
>
> ### -- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
>
> -- Unit session-7.scope has begun starting up. Jan 01 11:01:01 cluster1 CROND[24145]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly) Jan 01
>   11:01:01 cluster1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[24148]: starting
>   0anacron Jan 01 11:01:01 cluster1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[24154]:
>   finished 0anacron

Here is my “/etc/httpd/conf.d/status.conf” file on both node

```
<Location /server-status>
        SetHandler server-status
        Require local
</Location>
```

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution.

In `httpd.conf` add:

```
PidFile /var/run/httpd.pid
```

Then, stop and start cluster.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. For rhel7, the path is `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid`

So, in `httpd.conf` add:

```
PidFile /var/run/httpd/httpd.pid
```

Then stop and start the cluster